# Self-oscillating converter circuit

Tags: transformer, converter

I need some help with understanding following DC-DC converter circuit:

(Just for clarification, the three windings are on the same transformer core)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa4ZSb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My questions are:

1. How would you classify topology of this converter? Can it be called a self-oscillating flyback?
2. Why is secondary winding (L3) directly connected to the other windings? Is there any advantage over more common separated secondary winding?
3. Would you recommend to add any snubber network to protect the switching transistor againist voltage spikes?

Comment: Yes. Without even looking at this more than a glance, you want to add a diode between the BJT base and ground to protect it from negative-going spikes. I haven't looked at it enough to know if this will affect the output voltage or efficiency, though. But it's pretty obvious the BJT's BE junction will be avalanching without the diode. Is the circuit supposed to use both diodes in series that are in the BAV99 package?

Comment: BAV99 is only good for about 80V but the inductor will produce hundreds of volts. are you using that diode to regulate the output voltage?

Comment: I planned to use a BAV21 (or 2 in series), but I didn't find them in the list, so I picked up another type. UF4007 would be probably a better choice. There will be a feedback regulation (not shown here) which will limit the output voltage to about 250 V.

Comment: This is a Joule Thief with the addition of L3 and it's catch diode, which are attached like an autotransformer to achieve higher voltages than L2 could reach by itself. I think it also lessens the "voltage stress" on the transistor, but I'm not sure about that -- Can someone concur? Also, I do consider a Joule Thief to be both a blocking oscillator, and a self-oscillating flyback, as well as a boost converter, so I'm not contradicting the 2 answers already posted.

Answer (score 3):

1. Sure, it is a self-oscillating flyback.
2. If you don't need primary to secondary isolation, stacking the windings gives a little higher output voltage.
3. Yes, if the transformer has any significant leakage inductance (it will) then a snubber is a good idea to protect the transistor.

Having said all that, this circuit's operation will vary a lot with component tolerances, and the efficiency and reliability may be poor depending on the switching frequency.

I would recommend using a modern boost controller and MOSFET for a more efficient reliable design.

Answer (score 3):

I'd call this a [blocking oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_oscillator).

You save 26 turns on the secondary and get the supply voltage added on top of that by putting the windings in series.

You can put a scope on it and see what the voltages actually are with your given transformer construction. The BC547C is good for about 45V so it can handle spikes well beyond the 3.6V supply. If it doesn't need it, don't add it.